# What is the jargon that refers to things that come after a "." like .append or .count?

Tags: python

There are keywords like if/in as well as operators like +/- but im looking for a list of things that are like .append

Specifically something that allows you to merge the results of two different loops. Thanks.

Comment: I am very confused as to what you are asking.  You want a list of list operations?

Comment: If so: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: sorry I am new to this. I'm asking what is the group name that encompasses things like ".append" and ".format"

Comment: Post the code you have tried and expected output

Comment: What do you mean "group name"? Methods?

Comment: They are just methods.

Comment: no for example if,return and, else are classed as keywords in python what are .format and .append classed as?

Comment: built-in methods of built-in str and list classes, respectively.

Comment: oh ok the word i was looking for is methods thank you all I should be ok from here.

Comment: Maybe _member functions_? Since they are all part of some class respectively, thats what we were taught in university anyhow. But I agree, _method_ is accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are classed as `methods`.

**Proof:**

> Here are all of the methods of list objects:

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures

> The Formatter class has the following public methods:

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting